# Is it possible to set the norm parameter in df.plot.scatter?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, matplotlib, plot, keyword-argument

I prefer `df.plot.scatter()` rather than `plt.scatter()` when doing data exploration. However I'm unable

#### Generate Data

```py
n = 1000
data = dict(
    x = np.random.rand(n) + np.random.rand(1)[0],
    y = np.random.rand(n) + np.random.rand(1)[0],
    # color dimension
    z = np.exp(np.random.rand(n)) - np.exp(np.random.rand(n)).mean(),
)
# throw it in a dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

#### Plotting with `plt.scatter`

The left plot uses `CenteredNorm` to ensure its colorbar is centered around zero no matter the distribution skew.

```py
cmap='bwr'
fig, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(figsize=(20, 8), ncols=2)
sc = ax1.scatter(x=data['x'], y=data['y'], c=data['z'], cmap=cmap, norm=colors.CenteredNorm())
fig.colorbar(sc, ax=ax1)

sc = ax2.scatter(x=data['x'], y=data['y'], c=data['z'], cmap=cmap)
fig.colorbar(sc, ax=ax2)
plt.show()
```

[image]

#### Plotting with `df.plot.scatter`

```py
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
fig, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(figsize=(10, 4), ncols=2)
df.plot.scatter(x='x', y='y', c='z', norm=colors.CenteredNorm(), cmap=cmap, ax=ax1)
df.plot.scatter(x='x', y='y', c='z', cmap=cmap, ax=ax2)

plt.show()
```

Attempting the same with pandas inbuilt plotting API, raises the error:

```py
TypeError: matplotlib.axes._axes.Axes.scatter() got multiple values for keyword argument 'norm'
```

#### Using `kwargs` parameters

```py
kwargs = dict(norm=colors.CenteredNorm())
df.plot.scatter(x='x', y='y', c='z',
                cmap=cmap,
                ax=ax1
                **kwargs)
```

After a code correction from [tdy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13138364/tdy), the snippet raises the same error:

```py
TypeError: matplotlib.axes._axes.Axes.scatter() got multiple values for keyword argument 'norm'
```

Is there any way of setting the norm param via pandas inbuilt plotting API?

Comment: This doesn't fix the issue `norm` issue, but note that `kwargs` should be unpacked like `df.plot.scatter(x='x', y='y', c='z', cmap=cmap, ax=ax1, **{'norm': colors.CenteredNorm()})`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update:**

Starting in pandas 1.5.0, the `norm` parameter will work as expected with `df.plot.scatter`. The bug got fixed in [PR #45966](http://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/pull/45966).

---

**Original bug:**

[`df.plot.scatter`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.plot.scatter.html) passes kwargs to [`df.plot`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.plot.html) which passes kwargs to [`ax.scatter`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.scatter.html).

The issue is that pandas already sets a `norm`:

> <sup>[`plotting/_matplotlib/core.py#L1114-L1122`](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/v1.4.1/pandas/plotting/_matplotlib/core.py#L1114-L1122)</sup>
>
> ```py
> scatter = ax.scatter(
>     data[x].values,
>     data[y].values,
>     c=c_values,
>     label=label,
>     cmap=cmap,
>     norm=norm,
>     **self.kwds,
> )
> ```

This `norm` is defined as either a `BoundaryNorm` or `None`:

> <sup>[`plotting/_matplotlib/core.py#L1095-L1103`](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/v1.4.1/pandas/plotting/_matplotlib/core.py#L1095-L1103)</sup>
>
> ```py
> if color_by_categorical:
>     # ...
>     norm = colors.BoundaryNorm(bounds, cmap.N)
> else:
>     norm = None
> ```

So passing another `norm` via kwargs will produce the "multiple values" error.

This can be reproduced in pure matplotlib:

```py
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.scatter(0, 42, norm=None, **{'norm': colors.CenteredNorm()})

# TypeError: matplotlib.axes._axes.Axes.scatter() got multiple values for keyword argument 'norm'
```

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by @tdy, unpacking kwargs doesn't do the trick.

The function [`df.plot.scatter`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.plot.scatter.html) takes the parameters `x, y, s, c`. Additional kwargs are passed to [`df.plot`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.plot.html). The following parameters are supported:

- x
- y
- kind
- ax
- subplots
- sharex
- sharey
- layout
- figsize
- use_index
- title
- grid
- legend
- style
- logx
- logy
- loglog
- xticks
- yticks
- xlim
- ylim
- rot
- fontsize
- colormap
- table
- yerr
- xerr
- secondary_y
- sort_columns

...but it will not take the parameter `norm`. That would require extending [pandas source code](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/v0.25.0/pandas/plotting/_core.py#L504-L1533).

Comment: There's actually another level of redirection after `df.plot`, so it does successfully pass `norm` down to `ax.scatter`. I dug around a bit more and found the root cause.

Comment: Great find! I can see the issue is still hot. I'll accept [your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71297652/5684214) for now. Let's try to keep an eye on the issue. Once released, the accepted answer should point to upgrading to that pandas release.