# pandas scatter plot log colorbar

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, plot

I am plotting a dataframe in pandas that uses another column for color and I would like to use a log normalized colormap.

[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17201172/a-logarithmic-colorbar-in-matplotlib-scatter-plot) shows that in plain matplotlib you can use a log-normalized colormap by simply adding `norm=matplotlib.colors.LogNorm()` to the `.scatter()` method. When I do that for pandas, though it causes a TypeError: `TypeError: matplotlib.axes._axes.Axes.scatter() got multiple values for keyword argument 'norm'`.

#### Minimum Reproducible Example

```
example_data = pd.DataFrame({'sample_no': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6], 
                'data1': [10, 15, 12, 10, 13, 14], 
                'data2': [0.1, 1, 5, 10, 12, 5]})
```

Plotting like this:

```
example_data.plot.scatter('sample_no', 'data1', c='data2', cmap='viridis',)
```

Yields a nice graph.
[image]

Adding the `norm` argument yields the error above.

```
example_data.plot.scatter('sample_no', 'data1', c='data2', cmap='viridis',
                          norm=matplotlib.colors.LogNorm())
```

#### Full slack trace

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
/Users/rwegener/repos/sarp_lessons/snippets/More mapping/flight_track.ipynb Cell 45' in <cell line: 1>()
----> 1 example_data.plot.scatter('sample_no', 'data1', c='data2', cmap='viridis',
      2                           norm=matplotlib.colors.LogNorm())

File ~/.pyenv/versions/miniconda3-4.7.12/envs/sarp/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pandas/plotting/_core.py:1669, in PlotAccessor.scatter(self, x, y, s, c, **kwargs)
   1586 def scatter(self, x, y, s=None, c=None, **kwargs):
   1587     """
   1588     Create a scatter plot with varying marker point size and color.
   1589 
   (...)
   1667         ...                       colormap='viridis')
   1668     """
-> 1669     return self(kind="scatter", x=x, y=y, s=s, c=c, **kwargs)

File ~/.pyenv/versions/miniconda3-4.7.12/envs/sarp/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pandas/plotting/_core.py:917, in PlotAccessor.__call__(self, *args, **kwargs)
    915 if kind in self._dataframe_kinds:
    916     if isinstance(data, ABCDataFrame):
--> 917         return plot_backend.plot(data, x=x, y=y, kind=kind, **kwargs)
    918     else:
    919         raise ValueError(f"plot kind {kind} can only be used for data frames")

File ~/.pyenv/versions/miniconda3-4.7.12/envs/sarp/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pandas/plotting/_matplotlib/__init__.py:71, in plot(data, kind, **kwargs)
     69         kwargs["ax"] = getattr(ax, "left_ax", ax)
     70 plot_obj = PLOT_CLASSES[kind](data, **kwargs)
---> 71 plot_obj.generate()
     72 plot_obj.draw()
     73 return plot_obj.result

File ~/.pyenv/versions/miniconda3-4.7.12/envs/sarp/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pandas/plotting/_matplotlib/core.py:329, in MPLPlot.generate(self)
    327 self._compute_plot_data()
    328 self._setup_subplots()
--> 329 self._make_plot()
    330 self._add_table()
    331 self._make_legend()

File ~/.pyenv/versions/miniconda3-4.7.12/envs/sarp/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pandas/plotting/_matplotlib/core.py:1114, in ScatterPlot._make_plot(self)
   1112 else:
   1113     label = None
-> 1114 scatter = ax.scatter(
   1115     data[x].values,
   1116     data[y].values,
   1117     c=c_values,
   1118     label=label,
   1119     cmap=cmap,
   1120     norm=norm,
   1121     **self.kwds,
   1122 )
   1123 if cb:
   1124     cbar_label = c if c_is_column else ""

TypeError: matplotlib.axes._axes.Axes.scatter() got multiple values for keyword argument 'norm'
```

Comment: This is a bug in `df.plot.scatter`. The bug has been fixed, but it won't take effect until pandas 1.5.0: https://stackoverflow.com/a/71297652/13138364

Answer (score 0):

You could apply log norm to data1 and data2 and then create the scatter plot. It would produce the intended effect.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like a bug in `class ScatterPlot` in [_matplotlib/core.py](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/d5f2e5c02611d3986f58b97cc8645402be048239/pandas/plotting/_matplotlib/core.py)

```
if color_by_categorical:
    from matplotlib import colors

    n_cats = len(self.data[c].cat.categories)
    cmap = colors.ListedColormap([cmap(i) for i in range(cmap.N)])
    bounds = np.linspace(0, n_cats, n_cats + 1)
    norm = colors.BoundaryNorm(bounds, cmap.N)
else:
    norm = self.kwds.pop("norm", None)
```

Sets `norm` local variable and later uses it in

```
scatter = ax.scatter(
    data[x].values,
    data[y].values,
    c=c_values,
    label=label,
    cmap=cmap,
    norm=norm,
    **self.kwds,
)
```

However, the last parameter `self.kwds` already contains `norm` named parameter, which you sent, so you end up with two `norm`, and Python can't handle this.

It seems like there was an attempt to fix it at [commit 1cad74e1ee3b5144f6ef774aeed6ae3152d28d6a](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/commit/1cad74e1ee3b5144f6ef774aeed6ae3152d28d6a), but the commit wasn't successful.

Answer (score 0):

Use matplotlib’ s scatter rather than pandas if the pandas one won’t let you input a norm:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.scatter(sample_data[‘sample_no’], sample_data[‘data1’], norm=matplotlib.colors.LogNorm())
```